# Largest connected group of identically distributed nodes in d.r.v sample graph

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, nonparametric, graph-theory

I have come across an unfamiliar and somewhat interesting problem while attempting to write an algorithm for an image processing application and was wondering if any of you had any ideas that might be able to help me out.

I have an undirected graph G=(V,E), with |V|=1000, each node being adjacent to maybe 5 other nodes.

Each Vi is a set of Ni(usually around 50) observations of an unknown d.r.v, Xi which could be different for each node (or equally could be the same), we do however know that all Xi are constrained to integers in the interval [0,255].

Given some start node V0, and a confidence level of let's say 90%, I am looking to find the largest connected group of nodes, Vconn, such that we are 90% sure they are all samples drawn from the same distribution.

Due to the large size of the graph, a brute force search is infeasible but some smarter frontier based approach would be much better. For example, the following algorithm could work but it seems like any notion of confidence is discarded as there is an (I'm pretty sure incorrect) assumption of transitivity built in:

```
1. Calculate the EDF (F: V -> P([0,255] X Z) for each node and store it with the node
2. Keep a frontier of candidates to join the selection, initially the neighbors of V0
3. While the frontier is not empty:
4.    Remove a candidate from the frontier
5.    Carry out Anderson-Darling test or something similar between candidate and selection
6.    If it passes then add it to the selection and combine EDFs, add its neighbors to the frontier
7. Return selection
```

The problem being this takes any node that it is confident is identically distributed and then adds it to the current "ground truth" and I'm not convinced that this correctly enforces the property that they all have a 90% chance of being identically distributed individually.

Does anybody have any suggestions for a way that this could be computed reasonably accurately and efficiently? How much easier would the problem become if we could assume that all Xi were normally distributed? What if the exact confidence level is not important but instead we just need a parameter that can be tweaked to select anywhere between just V0 and the whole of V?

I'd greatly appreciate any help anyone can give :)